# How to extract multiple tables in a multiple website through power query

Tags: excel, database, powerbi, powerquery

Want to know to extract data tables in a website through power query and the tables have same headers and multiple websites with same table structure.

Need to know the code

Comment: You need to provide us with some more information.  What specifically is giving you trouble?  What have you tried so far to solve your problem?  Can you give us the website? What is the data that you're trying to get?

Comment: @RyanB. thanks for helping me out.

Comment: thanks for helping me out.I need to extract data from multiple websites, which has multiple tables in each website. Now i have been able to extract information from different websites but i was able to extract one table in each website. (https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/how-to-extract-data-from-multiple-webpages/) . I have use this method to scrap the data.   The following are the sample websites - (http://www.goo-net-exchange.com/catalog/NISSAN__BLUEBIRD/), ( http://www.goo-net-exchange.com/catalog/NISSAN__BASSARA/), (http://www.goo-net-exchange.com/catalog/NISSAN__CARAVAN_COACH/)

Comment: I need a way to extract all the tables in the those URL . The header are the same. Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this may help. This will grab all the data from all the tables on the site goo-net-exchange.com/catalog/NISSAN__BLUEBIRD, appended together in one table.

From within Power Query, click Home > New Source > Other Sources > Web. Then enter your link and click OK:

[image]

Then click on the folder and click OK.

[image]

Then filter out the Source that isn't a table.

[image]

Then right-click on the Data column's title and Remove Other Columns.

[image]

[image]

Then click on [image] to expand all the tables.

[image]

Click OK.

*****ADDED AFTER YOUR COMMENT/QUESTION*****

I went into Power Query and opened the query that was created from the above activity. Then I changed `"http://www.goo-net-exchange.com/catalog/NISSAN__BLUEBIRD/"` in the Source line to `Site`, so the line now reads: `Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(Site)),`.

Then I inserted these two lines above the original let in the code, still keeping that original let in place (so now there are two let) lines:

```
let 
Source = (Site) =>
```

Then I inserted these two lines below the original last line of the code:

```
in
Source
```

These four line transformed what I had before into a function.

Next, I renamed my query to CarSites...just because I felt like it.

Then I made sure everything was saved and returned to Excel.

In Excel, I made a new table with your three websites' URLs:

[image]

I named the table Table1.

Then I clicked on the table (Table1) and then Data > From Table to create another query in Power Query from that table.

Then I clicked on Add Column > Invoke Custom Function, and set up the entries like this, below, and clicked OK:

[image]

It gave me this:

[image]

Each table in the CarSites column is the collection of appended tables for each site listed in the LinkURL column (like you had for the Nissan BlueBird site before). You can delete the LinkURL column and expand the CarSites column to get one single appended column of all the sites.

Based on what I see from the table's info, you'll still have some work to do to clean things up with this info that you pull. For instance, the tables don't readily indicate which car and year each line is providing information about. You'll need to figure out how to map the name and year to each line.

You'll want to do that work in the function.

Good luck!

In case it helps, here's my M code:

For the CarSites function:

```
let 
Source = (Site) =>
let
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(Site)),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Source] = "Table")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Data"}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Data", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "MODEL TYPE", "MODEL", "ENGINE", "DOOR", "T/M DRIVE", "Dimension", "WEIGHT", "MSRP", "Find Used Cars"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "MODEL TYPE", "MODEL", "ENGINE", "DOOR", "T/M DRIVE", "Dimension", "WEIGHT", "MSRP", "Find Used Cars"})
in
#"Expanded Data"
in
Source
```

And for the Table1 query:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "CarSites", each CarSites([LinkURL]))
in
#"Invoked Custom Function"
```

Comment: Hi @marc, The issue with the above method is that,  there are about more than 100 websites (different car models), so it will take long time if I do the above method. Is there any method where we can list all the URL in one go and extract all the tables in each websites. Please let me Know. Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I added more at the end of my previous answer, to address automatically getting the information from multiple sites.

Comment: Hi Marc thanks alot for helping me out. Ill try this and should work. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Create Empty Query in PQ, go to Advanced Editor, press Ctrl-A, and paste this text:

`= (url) => let
        Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(url)),
        Custom1 = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Value.Is([Data], type table) and Table.RowCount([Data])>0 and List.First(Table.ColumnNames([Data])) = "MODEL TYPE"),
        #"Expanded Data" = let c = List.Accumulate(Table.ColumnNames(List.First(Custom1[Data])), {{},{}}, (s,c)=> {s{0} & {c}, s{1} & {"Data." & c}}) in Table.ExpandTableColumn(Custom1, "Data", c{0}, c{1})
    in
        #"Expanded Data"`

Name a query as e.g. "Q"
Then import a table with all your urls, and add a Custom column to it with

```
Q(Name of column with urls)
```

Possibly you'll have to set up a Privacy level to Public, if PQ asks you for that.

Then expand added column. That's it.

Comment: Hey @Andery Thanks a lot for helping me out. Your saving me time . Thanks again.